# Javascript: Replacing an Objects Property Value

Tags: javascript, object

```
var obj = {
    prop1: "value1",
    prop2: "value2",
    prop3: "value3"
}
```

How do I replace each prop of obj with a string?

Desired result:

```
var obj = {
   prop1: "foo",
   prop2: "foo",
   prop3: "foo"
}
```

Comment: Loop over the properties and set the value of each to your desired value.

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice for looping over objects you should use hasOwnProperty to make sure to only overwrite properties and not functions unless you are 100% certain that the loop will never occur on an object holding anything but properties like illustrated in your example. The second check is to make sure that it does not overwrite any objects within the object should those exist.

```
var obj = {
    prop1: "value1",
    prop2: "value2",
    prop3: "value3",
    prop4: {
        test: "test"
    }
}
for (var p in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p) && (typeof obj[p]) != "object") {
        obj[p] = "foo"
    }
}
```

Comment: No need for `hasOwnProperty`, `obj` does not have other methods and inherits nothing enumerable.

Comment: I know. It is a best practice to use hasOwnProperty though, which is why I mentioned it. In some cases the object might contain other object types that one would not want to overwrite. The updated code I just posted also accounts for objects within the object.

Comment: No, it's not a best practice in every-day code that you write to deal with data objects - it's just superfluous fluff that makes the code hard to read and understand. It *is* a good practice to use it in generic (e.g. library) function that *might* have to deal with instances.

Comment: Also, you update makes no sense at all. Neither do I understand what this does try to guard against (or why that would be necessary), nor does the code actually work. `typeof` *never* yield `"[object object]"`, and most property values won't have a `.toLowerCase()` method so it'll throw when you try to invoke it.

Comment: Still makes no sense to me. That `toLowerCase` is not needed, and why would you exclude objects? OP said he wants to replace *every* property.

Comment: I was thinking of the result for "toString", which would be "[Object object]" instead of just "object".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89431/discussion-between-joshua-dannemann-and-bergi).

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over all keys and set the properties to the desired value.

```js
var obj = {
        prop1: "value1",
        prop2: "value2",
        prop3: "value3"
    };
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
    obj[key] = 'foo';
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(obj, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: That might work on this object, but in some cases, the object might contain other objects, functions, and properties. Would this not overwrite the values for those members as well as the strings?

Comment: I can not see this requirement in the question ... In the real world the assignment ist covered by type checking.

Comment: In my world it is, but I design frameworks and libraries, so I guess from my perspective whenever I would have to do something like this, I cannot expect that the object my function is used on will in fact only contain properties.

Comment: By the way, I like the style of your for loop. That is much more efficient.